# How to add images or another text in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have the below code and I want to replace the "Good....." text wih images and/or with some text, tables using HTML. I tried with innerHTML, no success. I guess I need some new variables.

```
var greeting;
function myFunction() {
    var time = new Date().getHours();
    if (time < 10) {
        greeting = "Good morning";
    } 
    else if (time < 18) {
        greeting = "Good day";
    }
    else if (time < 22) {
        greeting = "Good evening";
    } 
    else {
        greeting = "Good night";
    }
}

myFunction();
var createP = document.createElement('p');
document.getElementById('demo').appendChild(createP);
createP.innerHTML = greeting;
console.log(createP);
```

Comment: Do you mean to replace text of good with image right?

Comment: I guess you can use `greeting.replace()` to do that

Comment: Your function `myFunction` also needs a return statement. Every function in JavaScript returns undefined unless otherwise specified.

Answer (score 2):

I have created all 3 demos with different pieces of code.

```js
var greeting;

function myFunction(replaceText) {
  var time = new Date().getHours();
  if (time < 10) {
    greeting = "Good morning";
  } else if (time < 18) {
    greeting = "Good day";
  } else if (time < 22) {
    greeting = "Good evening";
  } else {
    greeting = "Good night";
  }
  greeting = greeting.replace(/good/gi, replaceText);
}

myFunction("test");
var createP = document.createElement('p');
document.getElementById('demo').appendChild(createP);
createP.innerHTML = greeting;
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

**another way**

```js
 var greeting;

 function myFunction(replaceText) {
   var time = new Date().getHours();
   if (time < 10) {
     greeting = "Good morning";
   } else if (time < 18) {
     greeting = "Good day";
   } else if (time < 22) {
     greeting = "Good evening";
   } else {
     greeting = "Good night";
   }
   greeting = greeting.replace(/good/gi, replaceText);
 }

 myFunction("test");
 var createP = document.createElement('p');
 document.getElementById('demo').appendChild(createP);
 createP.innerHTML = greeting;
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

```js
var greeting;

function myFunction() {
  var time = new Date().getHours();
  if (time < 10) {
    greeting = "Good morning";
  } else if (time < 18) {
    greeting = "Good day";
  } else if (time < 22) {
    greeting = "Good evening";
  } else {
    greeting = "Good night";
  }

}

myFunction();
greeting = greeting.replace(/good/gi, '<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/9/95/Test_image.jpg"/>');
var createP = document.createElement('p');
document.getElementById('demo').appendChild(createP);
createP.innerHTML = greeting;
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

**replace image**

Comment: It would also be nice to add a more explicit return statement to `myFunction` so the console doesn't continue returning 'undefined' when the function is invoked in your second code snippet.

Comment: @TannerDolby mistakenly I forgot to remove the console statement.

Comment: Understandable. I appreciate your use of Regular expressions. Upvoted.

Comment: Thx for your reply. I tested all examples, but I want to have the posibiity to have different images and text based on the hours. Iof Good morning to be able to write a code in HTML with different tags (ul, li, p, div and so on and also to add img, figcaption tags. The same for Good day or Good night.

Comment: I am still not getting you. can you explain me with example? So I will help you.

Comment: Hi, instead of greeting= "Good morning" (the same for the rest of the texts) to have something like that greeting =" <ul><li> text</li></ul><br> <p> another text</p><br><img src='path-to-the-image'><br><p>text bla bla bla</p><br>"

Answer (score 0):

For the multi line text I solved it with the below code (Only a part of it). I have just a simple break rule. I am looking for a option to add images.

```
 greeting = "Nice to meet you! Are you OK? <br> I hope so!";
```

To add an image I did as below.

```
 greeting = "Nice to meet you! <br> See ya later <br> and so on";
 greeting+= '<img class="img-fluid" src="src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/9/95/Test_image.jpg">';
```